Is there any parameter in the Facebook Marketing API that translates the dynamic parameters?
The request I am making is:
[GET] graph.facebook.com/v20.0/[ad_id]/adcreatives?fields=name,url_tags
The Facebook API is bringing me this:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "{{product.name}} XXXX",
      "url_tags": "utm_source={{site_source_name}}&utm_medium={{placement}}&utm_campaign={{campaign.name}}&utm_content={{ad.name}}",
      "id": "XXXXX"
    }
  ]
}

I want to translate the url_tags and name fields so that it brings me the real url and name that will be displayed for that creative.
I tried to read the documentation and test all parameters, but I didn't find anything.
